# System.Today() and System.Now() in test class

Tags: unit-testing, salesforce, apex-code

How can we mockup System.Today() and System.Now() in Test class for any further logic?

I remember SF having the limitation a while back but not sure if they came up with anything new.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on what your code is doing, it is possible to modify your code to pull the logic involved into a separate method where you pass in System.Today() or System.Now(). At that point you can test that component and pass in a Date/DateTime of your choosing.

For example, if this was your code you could do the following for testability:

```
System.debug(System.now().addDays(2));
```

Changes to:

```
public static DateTime addDays(DateTime d, Integer i)
{
    return d.addDays(i);
}

System.debug(addDays(System.now(), 2));
```